# Trouble installing avm+.sty with MiKTeX 2.9

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9, avm

I am trying to install the package `avm+.sty` to MiKTeX 2.9. but nothing seems to work. Am I supposed to create a special path for this package?

What is the procedure for installing `*.sty` files with MiKTeX 2.9?

Comment: in your title you say `avm+.xty` and in your question you say `ams+.sty` which is it? is there a link to either package?

Comment: I assume you mean this http://vlado.cs.dal.ca/tex/avm/avm+.sty  it would work if you just placed it in the same folder as your document.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te)